# Hashmaps and BFS

Tags: java, hashmap

I am trying to use BFS to find the shortest path to a spot in a 2x2 array. However, I am coming across an issue where my HashMap is always entering null values so I can't iterate through the HashMap to get the values I need. I'm not sure if my code shows enough for this and I know it isn't the best when it comes to structuring and coding, but I just want to know why the HashMap is only holding null values.

The code works fine until I need to add values to the arraylist once the button is found. In the while loop where the "nextSpot" != "button", I am getting only null values and also when I tried printing the values of the HashMap at the end of the while loop, it still only had null values.

It's not a matter of the return null statement at the end either, I just put that there because I assumed that the function would work properly regardless.

```
    public static ArrayList<int[]> BFSBOT1(char[][] array, int[] bot, int[] button){
        printGrid(array, array.length);
        Queue<int[]> queue = new LinkedList<>();
        HashMap<int[], int[]> mapOfEverything = new HashMap<>();
        boolean[][] visited = new boolean[array.length][array.length];

        queue.add(bot);
        visited[bot[0]][bot[1]] = true;
        

        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            
            int[] nextSpot = queue.remove();


            if(nextSpot[0] == button[0] && nextSpot[1] == button[1]){
                ArrayList<int[]> shortestPath = new ArrayList<>();
                int[] path = button;
                while(path[0] != bot[0] && path[1] != bot[1]){
                    shortestPath.add(path);
                    path = mapOfEverything.get(path);
                }
                return shortestPath;

            }
            int neighbors = countNeighbors(array, array.length, nextSpot[0], nextSpot[1]);
            Queue <int[]> neighborQueue = neighbors(array, array.length,nextSpot[0] ,nextSpot[1]);

            for(int i = 0; i < neighbors; i++){
                int[] variable1 = neighborQueue.remove();
                int c = variable1[0];
                int d = variable1[1];

                if(variable1[0] == button[0] && variable1[1] == button[1]){
                    queue.clear();
                    queue.add(variable1);
                    break;
                }

                if(!visited[variable1[0]][variable1[1]]){
                    queue.add(variable1);
                    mapOfEverything.put(nextSpot, variable1);
                    visited[variable1[0]][variable1[1]] = true;


                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

I've tried different things like changing names, using specific points and just many different things but nothing seemed to work. I don't really understand why the HashMap doesn't contain any actual int[] values.

Comment: Create a Java fiddle here - https://javafiddle.leaningtech.com/ or anywhere - and share with test data. Above code has missing method implementations of `countNeighbors`, `neighbors`, and maynot be much important, but `printGrid` too.